# Google Plugin for Eclipse not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, wizard

wow.. some of my dreams just got true :) Great Tools! Still I've got a problem with it. I've got a pretty fresh install of `eclipse 4.2` + `Android Development Tools 20` + `Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.0.1` + `Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.0.1`

When I create a new clean Android Project and try to "generate app engine backend" I get an error and a lot of missing dependencies and code.. Error message is useless and console tells me everything worked

Error: `Error in Generating Backend Project`

Console: `DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 1 classes. Timings : input=80 ms, enhance=44 ms, total=124 ms. Consult the log for full details`

In my Create Wizard I also don't have the option for `App Engine Connected Android Project`

I double checked I've got all dependencies freshly installed via "Install new Software"

Link to Installed Software: http://sharetext.org/EFS2

I had the same Problem with Eclipse 3 and deleted it and made this new fresh install of Eclipse 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug which got fixed in one of the later versions, if you run into this check to update your GooglePlugin for Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem. Have you made any headway?

**EDIT**

Based on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/QIgMgvAdn3o/hdiLLD3HQeQJ I think we're supposed to hold off until the documentation is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had too the same exact problem. Instead of Eclipse 4.2 try using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo. It did work for me.